# SQL Server multiply times previous row value grouped by account

Tags: sql-server

Is there a good way to have a query that multiplies a value by the same calculated value (itself) from the previous row grouped by some column. Below I have a table with two accounts ordered by date. (minor twist, if there is no previous row use 1). Value is the calculated value and is calculated on each account individually.

Note: I have shown the calculation for Value in the parenthesis for each query result.

Initial Table

```
 Account      Date             ChangePct       
 547          10/24/17           .997715     
 547          10/26/17           .973493     
 547          10/27/17          1.001300     
 547          10/30/17           .999541     
 600          10/26/17          1.004650    
 600          10/27/17          1.000996    
 600          10/30/17           .995000    
 600          10/31/17           .996176
```

Query Results

```
 Account      Date             ChangePct       Value
 547          10/24/17           .997715     .997715    (.997715 * 1)
 547          10/26/17           .973493     .971268    (.973493 * .997715)
 547          10/27/17          1.001300     .972531    (1.001300 * .971268)
 547          10/30/17           .999541     .972084    (.999541 * .972531)
 600          10/26/17          1.004650    1.004650    (1.004650 * 1)
 600          10/27/17          1.000996    1.005651    (1.000996 * 1.004650)
 600          10/30/17           .995000    1.000622    (.995000 * 1.005651)
 600          10/31/17           .996176     .996796    (.996176  * 1.000622)
```

Comment: One approach would be to use a cursor for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SCHEMA:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  account INT,
  date1 date,
  change_pct decimal(7,6)
);

INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (547, STR_TO_DATE("10/24/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), .997715); 
INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (547, STR_TO_DATE("10/26/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), .973493);     
INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (547, STR_TO_DATE("10/27/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), 1.001300);     
INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (547, STR_TO_DATE("10/30/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), .999541);     
INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (600, STR_TO_DATE("10/26/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), 1.004650);    
INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (600, STR_TO_DATE("10/27/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), 1.000996 );   
INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (600, STR_TO_DATE("10/30/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), .995000);    
INSERT INTO test (account,date1,change_pct) VALUES (600, STR_TO_DATE("10/31/17", "%m/%d/%Y"), .996176);
```

**QUERY:**

```
select 
    account,
    date1,
    change_pct,
    @prev_acct as ss,
    case 
        when @prev_acct = 1 then 
            @prev_acct:=account 
        when @prev_acct = account then
            @prev_acct:=account
        when @prev_acct != account then
            @prev_acct:=account and @multi:=1
        else 
            @prev_acct:=account
    end as s,
    (@multi := change_pct * @multi) as value
from
    test,
    (select @multi:=1, @prev_acct:= 1) t1
order by
    account,
    date1;
```

[DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kxPZmUaZzGvJbpBeezT3t6/6)

Comment: I wanted to multiply value times the previous calculated value... so if anything you would want to user lag(a.calculation) but that doesn't work.

Comment: @BrianRice I could write a cursor that would do this calculation for you and store it in a temp table. Let me know if this would be a solution for you before I attempt it.

Comment: I think it would be great if you did this because it seems to be THE solution... Note: in your cursor code... the "CaclulatedValue" should start at 1 for each account... and be reset to 1 for each new account.

Comment: BTW: I did not know about the Lag function... thanks for that tidbit!

Comment: @BrianRice I have updated my answer and found a solution without a cursor. Please see DB Fiddle link for Query result and sample data.